# SQLite: Combine Date Column & Time Column

Tags: sqlite, datetime

i simply have two fields. dtStartTime and dtStartDate.

I want to do a query now which returns **one** combined field dtStart using **SQLite**

I have tried
SELECT (dtStartDate+dtStartTime) as dtStart1, from ...
but it returns wrong values...

Thank you, shorty

PS: Dates are stored as unixepoch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT datetime(d, t)
FROM (
  SELECT date('now') as d, time('now') as t) as dt;
```

Answer (score 0):

probably:

```
SELECT DATETIME(DATE(dtStartDate) || ' ' || TIME(dtStartTime)) FROM YourTable;
```